# Selector for when only one child exists in parent

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm playing around with CSS selectors and i'm wondering can i build a custom css selector to only work when there only one of class `.widget-button`, example code;

```
<div class='container a'>
  <div class='widget-a' />
  <div class='widget-b' />
  <div class='widget-button' /> 
  <div class='widget-b' />
</div>
```

So you would assume theres' a combination of pseudo selectors (`:only-child ?`) to this job  that will work for the above? Hoever the bellow example should no selections/styles applyied as there more then one that class.

```
<div class='container b'>
  <div class='widget-a' />
  <div class='widget-b' />
  <div class='widget-button' />
  <div class='widget-z' />
  <div class='widget-x' />
  <div class='widget-button' />
  <div class='widget-z' />
</div>
```

Here a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2L593m3x/

Comment: No, `:only-child` would select an element only if it is the _single_ child of its parent. As soon as the element has _any_ siblings, it is not an only child any more.

Comment: Talk about a misleading question title @CBroe

Comment: Would using a combination of first-of-type and last-of-type help?

Comment: @ClintonGreen not really, at least not without using different markup - all elements are of “type” `div` here. And :first-of-class/:last-of-class doesn’t exist (yet.)

Answer (score 7):

Only one child in parent:

```
p:has(br:first-child:last-child)
```

Bonus

```css
p:has(:only-child) { color:green }
```

```html
<p>has <em>multiple</em> <strong>elements</strong></p>
<p><em>has single element</em></p>
```

Comment: "Note that this is not supported in any browser yet" "It also isn't intended to work in stylesheets" [MDN :has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has). This means this answer doesn't have any practical value... yet.

Comment: `:has()` only works for `document.querySelector()`. Not in CSS

Comment: Seems to work fine in chrome, safari, firefox, opera and brave, not sure about windows https://jsfiddle.net/mrwildone/wyhLcmk5/

Comment: Upvoted because this will be the standard pure CSS way in the next few years.

Answer (score 6):

If you are fine with creating custom tags (or whenever [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) gets widespread support), you could use `:only-of-type`:

```css
div>* {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
}

widget-button:only-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <widget-a></widget-a>
  <widget-b></widget-b>
  <widget-button></widget-button>
  <widget-b></widget-b>
</div>
<div>
  <widget-a></widget-a>
  <widget-b></widget-b>
  <widget-button></widget-button>
  <widget-z></widget-z>
  <widget-x></widget-x>
  <widget-button></widget-button>
  <widget-z></widget-z>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

> can i build a custom css selector to only work when there only one of class

**Long story short:** No.

We keep getting questions here about how to select `nth-of-class`.

You *cannot* select `nth-of-class`.

You can select by **children**.

You can select by element **type**.

*You cannot select by element **class**.*

---

At *some* point, `nth-match` (and complementary selectors) *may* arrive:

**e.g.**

```
.widget-button:nth-match(2n+1)
.widget-button:first-match
.widget-button:last-match
.widget-button:only-match
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely yes, you can do it by chaining two different selectors:

- Is the first direct child.
- Is the last child of it's type.

  `.container > .widget-button:nth-child(1):last-child`

*Edit:* *Apparently I misunderstood the question, but this can be helpful in some other cases.*

Comment: This works if you have two elements or more in a div and want to add specific styles if inside the div there remains only one . I have a use case for this in a slider where i have two buttons in all slides but in the last slide there remains only one button and i want to give it margin bottom but not if there are more buttons inside the div . Long story short thank you :))

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DragutescuAlexandru, that was my point indeed, I guess I misunderstood the original question.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper div:not(:first-child:last-child) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">Container #1</div>
  <div class="container">Container #2</div>
  <div class="container">Container #3</div>
  <div class="container">Container #4</div>
  <div class="container">Container #5</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">Container #1</div>
</div>
```