# Hide parent div if child div doesn't have content

Tags: wordpress, tags, hide, parent

I'm trying to hide the parent element in Wordpress if the child has no tags. 
Тhis is the code:

```
<div id="tags">
   <h4 class="tag-title">Tags</h4>
    <?php the_tags( '', ' ', '<br />' ); ?>
</div>
```

I want to hide all div #tags if php string is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `has_tag()` to check if there is a tags.

```
<?php if(has_tag()) { ?>
<div id="tags">
   <h4 class="tag-title">Tags</h4>
    <?php the_tags( '', ' ', '<br />' ); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use html elements as the $before, $sep, and $after parameters for the_tags, you can hide #tags when there's only one child (the ).

Looking at this post: [Selector for when only one child exists in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979747/selector-for-when-only-one-child-exists-in-parent) I came up with the below example.

```
<style>
    .tags h4:nth-child(1):last-child{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div class='tags' id='tags1'>
    <h4>Some nonsense</h4>
</div>

<div class='tags' id='tags2'>
    <h4>Some nonsense</h4>
    <ul><li>Some</li><li>other</li></ul>
</div>
```